# Picklist control to create a new record

Tags: picklist, record

I am working on a project to manage the human ressources, well my question is: how can I control a picklist to create a new record.
Exemple: I go to Application tab, wich contain a picklist, among values I choose 'Time Off'. I want to redirect me to create a Time Off form ( Start date , End date ... etc) on a object Time off that 've already created.

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to use record type insead of picklist.

Comment: Okey I will try record type.. thank you for your answer

Comment: This question is also posted to Stackoverflow. I think that here (Salesforce) is the best location for it.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to one solution showing a button where the record type is being set instead of being allowed to default:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008kdbIAA

The key is that parameter "p3" is the record type. You'll need to replace the code segment

```
"p3" = "012500000009Wjw"
```

with something like

```
"p3" = IF ( ISPICKVAL(TypeToCreate, "Time Off"), "<record type id of TimeOff>", "<default record type (or nest more IFs>")
```

You could also use Visualforce and Apex for this.

Comment: I didnt get this solution, can you please explain it further more

Comment: I've assumed that you wanted to create the new record when the user makes a selection and then clicks on a button.  Am I correct?  If so, the code needs to be modified with your picklist values and record type IDs.  Also, I've assumed only two record types in my example, TimeOff and default.  Also, how many record types do you have?

Comment: Yes exactely! but how can I modifiy the 'save' button code behind in order to redirect me creat a time off new record!! 
Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can change how the "save" button works without going to Visualforce/Apex.  The code I reference would have to go into a custom button.  You could call it "Create attached record" or whatever you like.